# is python package grpcio from conda-forge or pypi build using boringssl?

Tags: python-3.x, pypi, boringssl, conda-forge, grpcio

I would like to be sure that the python package `grpcio` (version >= 1.38.1) that I need to install is using BoringSSL and not OpenSSL.  I was looking a conda-forge [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/grpcio) or pypi [pypi](https://pypi.org/project/grpcio/) or at the grpc site [grpc](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/python/quickstart/) but could find this info. I found some blog that mention that boringssl is used but without any reference [blog](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/python/python-build-grpcio-from-source/). Any suggestion how to find this info ? or it will use the available SSL lib from the system ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, BoringSSL is used for all `grpcio` pre-compiled wheels. However, not all of them enabled assembly optimization for encrption: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/ssl-performance.md

Building with OpenSSL is an option that people need to explicitly opt-in: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/setup.py#L138

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I am facing an issue like this one https://github.com/googleapis/python-logging/issues/412 and now I know that we use boringssl the issue is somewhere else.